# Wikipedia as a Workflowy

Tags: open-source, wiki, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base, writing

Is there a web application where the information is structured as an outline like
[workflowy](https://workflowy.com/) and users can edit it like a Wikipedia?
There should be plenty of information already, or at least it should be in a good
start for adding information.
Users could have the possibility to watch subtrees with information or particular notes (in the certain node).

Comment: Do you know [WikiData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikidata)?

Comment: @Robert I heard about it, but didn't explored it yet. Is there a similarity with the features I'm looking for?